# Restore Folder (rm -r disaster)

Tags: 16.04, backup, rm

I've just eliminated the /Desktop/ folder through rm -r that i shouldn't. I know there is no way to restore it but I would like to know if there is some automatic back up that I can use to restore my file. I'm using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @steeldriver I don't think this is a duplicate, as this one is asking about recovering data from a [possible] backup. While the other question is about recovering data using recovery tools

Comment: @FlyBob I don't think there's any backup enabled by default on Ubuntu. You have to enable it yourself for the first time.

Comment: @user68186 Unfortunately I deleted the entire /Desktop/ folder.

Comment: @user68186 Honestly I don't remember because I installed much time ago.

Comment: jut open "Backups" (Deja Dup) program and see if there is any backup...

Comment: @RoVo No backup

Comment: bad luck, then it's a duplicate ;-)